# Changing Grid View Data Source via triggering Drop Down List selected index change event

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview

I am designing a web based logistics system. in my view orders page , i have some drop down lists which are bound to data source and a grid view beside them . i want to change grid view data source when ever operator select a relevant drop down list. i wrote the code but it's not working , grid view does not show any data. please tell me what am i doing wrong.

```
//Code for firing drop down list event 

        public void ddlVehicleFire(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        GridView1.DataSource = VehicleDastaSource;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

//aspx page

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="VehicleDastaSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LGDB %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [vehicleID], [manufacturer], [VIN], [capacity], [weight_], [dateOfProduction] FROM [vehicle]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

 Drop down list
   asp:DropDownList ID="DDLVehicle" runat="server" DataSourceID="vehicle"     DataTextField="vehicleID" DataValueField="vehicleID" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlVehicleFire"></asp:DropDownList>
```

[image: by choosing vehicle ID i want to display relevant data inside grid view]

Comment: What is the problem with ua code.What error are you facing..

Comment: grid view does not show any thing

Comment: make dropdownlist autopostback property true

Comment: try the below posted answer..

Comment: Show complete markup of your GridView and SqlDataSource as well as the Dropdownlist's selected index changed.

Answer (score 0):

1.make autopostback true for dropdown

c#

```
if (IsPostBack)

  {
   //your code here; 
  }
```

vb.net

```
If IsPostBack Then
        'your code here;

End If
```

.aspx

```
<Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Id" 
            DataField="Id" ReadOnly="true" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CreatedBy" 
            ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Created By" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CreateTime" 
            ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Date Created"
            DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
    </Columns>
```

Comment: did that , not working ,is it any changes needed to apply on gridvew?

Comment: did you use bound fields in grid view..If so paste that code with you question

Comment: i just dragged and dropped a grid view from toolbox VS.

Comment: I have edited my code..you nedd to define bound fields..it will state which column is for which values..

Comment: i want to change grid view content dynamicallym by selecting each of drop down list, if i write this , so this will work only for one ddl